# Exclude 2 strings from data

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have data about 3 types of fruits and their quantity. I want to exclude 'Apple' and 'Pear' from my data but encounter the below error. Why is it so?

```
import pandas as pd

df=(pd.DataFrame({'Fruit':['Apple','Orange','Pear','Apple','Orange']
                    ,'Qty':[3,4,1,7,9]}))


df=df[df['Fruit'].str.contains('Apple'|'Pear')==False]
print(df)
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `|` operator should be in the string itself:

```
df[df['Fruit'].str.contains('Apple|Pear')==False]
```

Or, with the negation operator:

```
df[~df['Fruit'].str.contains('Apple|Pear')]
Out: 
    Fruit  Qty
1  Orange    4
4  Orange    9
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way of getting the same result is the use of `isin`

```
df[~df['Fruit'].isin(['Apple','Pear'])]

Out
    Fruit  Qty
1  Orange    4
4  Orange    9
```